# My app doesn't compile after Vue CLI 2 to 3 update

Tags: vue.js, compiler-errors, vue-cli

I get the following error since I switched from Vue CLI version 2 to 3:

> You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template
>   compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into
>   render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

Here's how I instantiate Vue:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  components: {
    UserStatus
  },
  data: {
    isLoading: true
  }
})
```

This worked with version 2, why not on version 3?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474081/871404) proposes to import `Vue`'s template compiler via `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js';`, however this creates issues with `Vuetify`, and I still don't understand why there's any need to import the template compiler if version 2 didn't need to.

Just in case here's [the content of my index.html](https://github.com/fabricepallaud/timelog/blob/master/index.html). Also here's [my app's entire codebase](https://github.com/fabricepallaud/timelog).

As a reminder here's the out-of-the-box way of instantiating the main `Vue` instance, which is inadequate for me because it overrides whatever I manually wrote inside the `<div id="app">` element in my `index.html`, and also involves an `App.vue` component which I actually don't have or want to have:

```
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: show me `package.json`

Comment: If one answer solved the problem, please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The project seems to be missing quite a few dependencies related to vue cli 3. I forked your repo and brought package.json up to speed with a fresh install as well as aliased the runtime + compiler build of Vue.

Everything compiled and the console was clear of any errors related to compiling templates. The page never loaded, however, which I suspect is due to Firebase credentials missing.

You can find my updated fork [here on GitHub](https://github.com/digital-drifter/timelog/tree/vue-cli-3). Hope it helps!

Comment: I wish I could upvote you a couple of times. Your repo is such a great starting point, and it got me back into the game after 3 days of pulling hair. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue and I got it working by creating a vue.config.js file at my project's root directory and wrote the following code in it.

```js
module.exports = {
    runtimeCompiler: true,
};
```