# laravel with vue generating graphs component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, graph

I want to create a graph so I used components of graph to create a graph using this template

```
<template>
                    <div id="globalGraph">
                        <graph-bar
                                :width="600"
                                :height="400"
                                :axis-min="0"
                                :axis-max="50"
                                :labels="[ 'Global', 'China', 'nonChina' ]"
                                :values="values">
                            <note :text="'Global Chart'"></note>
                            <tooltip :names="names" :position="'left'"></tooltip>
                            <legends :names="names" :filter="true"></legends>
                        </graph-bar>
                    </div>
                </template>
```

then in my script i have

```
import bar from 'vue-graph/src/components/bar.js'
import NoteWidget from 'vue-graph/src/widgets/note.js'
import tooltip from 'vue-graph/src/widgets/tooltip.js'
import legends from 'vue-graph/src/widgets/legends.js'

export default {
    mounted() {
      console.log(bar)
      console.log(NoteWidget)
      console.log(tooltip)
      console.log(legends)
    },
    components: {
        'graph-bar' : bar,
        'legends' : legends,
        'note' : NoteWidget,
        'tooltip' : tooltip
    },
```

My Question is why do I get :

[image]

even if i added the `template tag` and the `mounted()`

> `UPDATE` : only the graph component is working the note the legend and tooltip not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails + webpacker + vue: "You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473630/rails-webpacker-vue-you-are-using-the-runtime-only-build-of-vue-where-the)

Comment: let me check the link

Comment: @DelenaMalan just FYI why is the bar graph component working the other note tooltip and legend only is not working